# How to automatically change a specific URL parameter from infoEnable=true to infoEnable=false on an Android phone through VPN or other means?

Tags: android, url-rewriting, android-vpn-service

My mom's Android phone has a weather app, and when she clicks to view detailed weather information in this app, it automatically opens the system browser and accesses this link: https://news.heytapdownload.com/weather/current.do?language=zh-cn&id=106577&unit=c&appFrom=2&openSource=15day_weather&template_rule=heytap&datasource=2&ver=13009002&frontCode=2.0&infoEnable=true&fromWeatherApp=true#/current.
However, the webpage has annoying ads. I noticed that changing the parameter infoEnable=true to infoEnable=false in this link eliminates the ads. Is there a simple way to modify this URL parameter? The system browser lacks ad-blocking functionality, and I've tried switching to a different default browser, but the weather app still redirects to the system default browser. I think using rule management in proxy software might help, but I don't know how to perform the specific operation. I don't know if my idea is right, please help me.thank you.